# Is this expression correct ? $\sum x_i \xrightarrow{\Delta x_i\ \sim \ \ 0^+} \int x\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I like math and I always add some mathematical notations, and formulas to my profile picture, which might help the people who are in my contacts to know more about maths.

Today I created the following expression with my little knowledge about integration.
$$\displaystyle\huge\sum x_i \xrightarrow{\Delta x_i\ \sim \ \ 0^+} \int x\ dx$$

I'm not well versed with MathJax so I'm also adding picture of my equation.

Can someone check if this expression make sense and doesn't contain any mistake, so that the viewer of my profile picture would get the correct knowledge?
How to make this expression more meaningful?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIqu7.png)

I'm not sure if this is a valid question here. I'm sorry if it is not!

Comment: The notation $\Delta x_i\sim 0^+$ (to my knowledge) is not standard.

Comment: @zz20s Can it be replaced with some other notation?

Comment: It appears what you're trying to do is right the definition of a Riemann integral as the limit of a Riemann sum. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Connection_with_integration for a basic introduction.

Comment: @zz20s I didn't understand what does it mean by $f(x_i*)$ what does the star here represents?

Comment: See the section towards the top of the page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Definition. $f(x_i^*)$ is by definition a sampling of the function values at $x_i^*\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$, where $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ is a subinterval of $[a,b]$.

Comment: I think it would be better if you talked about what you are trying to write by this notation. As of now, it is unclear.

Comment: I recommend using formal limit notation such as $\lim\limits_{\max\Delta x_i\to0} \sum_i x_i^*\Delta x_i$ instead of the handwriting-like annotated arrow.

Comment: Please don't rollback/revert the edits @YesYes. The Edits were made to make this question more readable to wide range of community members.

Answer (score 1):

First it makes no sense to talk about '$\delta x_i$' going to 0 when there is no '$\Delta x_i$' in the expression!  So you must have '$\sum x_i \Delta x_i$' rather than just '$\sum x_i$'.

Second, in order to HAVE a '$\Delta x_i$' you have to have divided an interval into sub-intervals.  In addition to just making '$\Delta x_i$' smaller you have to increase the number of sub-intervals and there are different ways to do that.

Comment: Ok as far as i understood you, is  $$\sum x_i \Delta x\xrightarrow{\Delta x_i\ \sim \ \ 0^+} \int x\ dx$$ correct?